# Increment variable after third time something else happened

Tags: c#

Excuse me for the silly question, but i can't manage to solve it.
How can i make something to happen `every third time` ?

Times(left number):

1. shipmentId=0
2. shipmentId=0
3. shipmentId=1
4. shipmentId=1
5. shipmentId=2
6. shipmentId=2 ....

   ```
   int occurrence = 0;
   int counter = 0;

    foreach (var el in elmOrderData)
           {

           if (el.Name == "shipmentIndex")
           {// we are entering here for every element that his name is "shipmentIndex"
               el.SetValue(shipmentId);
               secondTime++; 
           }
           if ((secondTime % 2) == 0)
           {// every third time we see "shipmentIndex" 
               secondTime = 1;
               shipmentId++;
           }
       }
   ```

Comment: what is wrong with the code snipped you posted? (except the typo)

Comment: You used both the JavaScript and the C# tag. Which language are you working in?

Comment: Presumably your if's are inside a loop or something so that you are not resetting ocurrence and counter to 0? Your logic looks sound.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: @n8wrl yes they are in a loop

Comment: ocurrence is set to 0, so on the second IF he gets increment by 1, each time

Comment: seems like the problem might be with `if(something happen)`. but you're not telling us what is happening there.

Comment: i updated my question, i meant after second time and not on the second itself

Comment: "every after second time" this doesn't make any sense - can you write an example in plain english? Like "the user clicks once, and nothing happens, the user clicks a 2nd time and nothing happens, the user clicks a third time, and a popup shows, the user clicks a fourth time and nothing happens..."

Comment: @Monkpit i updated my question- take a look ...

Comment: This post has nothing to do with javascript. The language used is C#

Comment: @SnareChops - yes, i know. but when i just posted it , i showed pseudo code .. so it was related to any language.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bool as in the following example. This will display messageboxes 1,3,5,7 and 9:

```
        bool test = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (test)
                MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());

            test = !test;
        }
```

Comment: got your solution - isn't there more obvious way?

Comment: i updated my question, i meant after second time and not on the second itself

Answer (score 0):

Trying to piece together your notes - whether 'it' happens every time or not. How about this?

```
int occurrence = 0;
int counter = 0;

foreach(var a in list)
{
    if(some_condition)
    {
        // do something..
        occurrence++
        if(occurrence % 2 == 0)
        {
            counter++
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just increment everytime and just divide by 2?

```
for(var i = 0; i<20; i++)
{
    var j = i / 2; // or bit shift
    //do work on j instead of i
}
```

Comment: thanks, in my case it's `foreach` loop and the if condition not always true - in that case the "index" will increment .. 
can you please change your answer to meet the question `foreach` loop with 2 `if`?